# C#, изменить размеры компонента MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#

Требуется изменить размеры, а именно высоту(height). Возможно ли? так просто он не меняет..Спасибо.

Comment: Его высота зависит от высоты шрифта

Comment: Недавно обнаружил, спасибо. Этим проблема и разрешилась

Answer (score 0):

Под изменением размера подразумевается свойство ClientSize? Ну или просто Size. + если под "так просто" имеется ввиду на форме, то попробуйте так `MaskedTextBox.Width =`